# Change activity label (Action bar title) from another activity?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was wondering if there is a way of changing one activity label from another activity?

Comment: by "activity label", do you mean the ActionBar Title?

Comment: only one activity is visible to the user at a time so there is no point in doing that

Comment: yes, Action bar title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only able to access one Activity instance at a time (visible one) so you can not call setTitle on invisable Activity directly.

The solution is you need to have Global variable to store the Activity title ( can use Static variable or Application field). When button click - you update Global variable. When Activity onResume, you set title in Global variable to the Activity by calling setTitle.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the title of actionbar using [setTitle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle(int)) method:

```
setTitle("awsome");
```

Comment: I use that when i am in an activity( which i want to change the name), but what if i am in another activity?

Comment: I want to change activity2 name from activity1

Comment: @Matt333 only one activity is visible at a time so I dont think changing the title of another activity is a good idea. You can send the title you want in a bundle and set it when your activity starts

Comment: But what if i need to change that label on button press( different label for different button)?

Answer (score 0):

Use an EventBus like: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Well use EventBus everywhere! EventBus is a very powerful concept!

An alternative would be to startActivityForResult() and the other one will return the new ActionBarTitle as result, but EventBus is definitely better!

Comment: I think that using an EventBus is a better solution than using a global variable suggested by @Loc Ha